# How to import the unmanaged dll with struct pointer?

Tags: c#, dllimport, unmanaged

I can DllImport common functions, but failed to import this kinds, below is DLL header files.

```
typedef struct
{
   VOID (* API_GetUID)(CHAR *pData, DWORD DataLen);

   DWORD (* API_GetChipType)();

} API_FUNCTION_STRUCT, *API_FUNCTION_STRUCT;

extern VOID WINAPI GetAPIObject(API_FUNCTION_STRUCT *pApiFunc);
```

I can't write the correct struct in C#.

```
public struct test
    {
        IntPtr  API_GetUID(IntPtr pData, int DataLen);
        IntPtr      API_GetChipType();
    } 

[DllImport(@"GDevice.dll")]
public static extern void GetAPIObject(ref test test_a);
```

Update:

```
public struct test
{
delegate void API_GetUID(IntPtr pData, int DataLen);
delegate void API_GetChipType();
}
```

Comment: I can import some function without pointer, I think I should write a struct in c#, but I don't know how to process pointer

Comment: @igelineau , I still can not get it work. Would you please help.

Comment: How exactly does this fail? And have you tried using an IntPtr for the method parameter instead of ref?

Comment: Your `struct` needs to contain some form of function pointer, not methods. Possibly delegates with proper marshaling annotations would work.

Comment: @CodesInChaos thanks, I have updated the content,I've tested delegate method, but I can't find way to call it. Would you please give me an example?

Comment: Your new struct contains delegate types, not fields of delegate type. But you probably need some form of marshal annotation as well, or probably even `IntPtr` fields which you then manually map to a function pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to use the [`Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getdelegateforfunctionpointer.aspx)

This takes an `IntPtr` pointing to a native method and gives you back a delegate you can call.

```
public struct test
{
    IntPtr API_GetUID;
    IntPtr API_GetChipType;
} 

[DllImport(@"GDevice.dll")]
public static extern void GetAPIObject(ref test test_a);

delegate void GetUID_Delegate(IntPtr pData, uint dataLen);
delegate uint GetChipType_Delegate();

test a = new test();
GetAPIObject(ref a);

GetUID_Delegate getUID = Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer<GetUID_Delegate>(a.API_GetUID);
GetChipType_Delegate getChipType = Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer<GetChipType_Delegate>(a.API_GetChipType);

uint chipType = getChipType();
```

## Edit

Alternatively use [UnmanagedFunctionPointerAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.unmanagedfunctionpointerattribute.aspx).

```
public struct test
{
    GetUID_Delegate API_GetUID;
    GetChipType_Delegate API_GetChipType;

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    delegate void GetUID_Delegate(IntPtr pData, uint dataLen);
    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    delegate uint GetChipType_Delegate();
} 

[DllImport(@"GDevice.dll")]
public static extern void GetAPIObject(ref test test_a);

test a = new test();
GetAPIObject(ref a);

uint chipType = a.API_GetChipType();
```

Comment: @lbasa thanks, I'm work on .Net CF, there is no GetDelegateForFunctionPointer.

Comment: Oh that could be tricky then, I'll edit for another way of doing this.